# Как подтвердить покупку Google Billing?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing

Как правильно подтвердить покупку приложения? Через 2-3 дня все покупки возвращаются обратно, но не понимаю, что сделал нет так.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    private lateinit var bind: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient

    private lateinit var consentInformation: ConsentInformation

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bind = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(bind.toolbar)

        val params = ConsentRequestParameters
            .Builder()
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
            .build()

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this)
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
            this,
            params,
            {
                UserMessagingPlatform.loadAndShowConsentFormIfRequired(
                    this@MainActivity
                ) { loadAndShowError ->
                    if (loadAndShowError != null) {
                        Log.w(
                            Constants.TAG, String.format(
                                "%s: %s",
                                loadAndShowError.errorCode,
                                loadAndShowError.message
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    if (consentInformation.canRequestAds()) {
                        initializeMobileAdsSdk()
                    }
                }
            },
            { requestConsentError ->
                // Consent gathering failed.
                Log.w(
                    Constants.TAG, String.format(
                        "%s: %s",
                        requestConsentError.errorCode,
                        requestConsentError.message
                    )
                )
            })
        if (consentInformation.canRequestAds())
            initializeMobileAdsSdk()

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(App.instance)
            .setListener(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

    }


    // обновление информации о покупках
    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(App.instance)
            .setListener(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            for (purchase in purchases)
                handlePurchase(purchase)
        } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
            showMessage(getString(R.string.snackbar_reset_app))
            SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion = true
        } else handleBillingError(billingResult.responseCode)
    }


    // установка соединения с google play для покупок
    private fun establishConnection() {
        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    getSingleInAppDetail()
                } else retryBillingServiceConnection()
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                retryBillingServiceConnection()
            }
        })
    }


    // повторное соединение с google play для покупок
    private fun retryBillingServiceConnection() {
        var tries = 1
        val maxTries = 3
        var isConnectionEstablished = false

        do {
            try {
                billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                        retryBillingServiceConnection()
                    }

                    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                        tries++
                        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                            isConnectionEstablished = true
                        else if (tries == maxTries)
                            handleBillingError(billingResult.responseCode)
                    }
                })
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                tries++
            }
        } while (tries <= maxTries && !isConnectionEstablished)

        if (!isConnectionEstablished)
            handleBillingError(-1)
    }


    // список доступных покупок
    private fun getSingleInAppDetail() {
        val queryProductDetailsParams =
            QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductList(
                    listOf(
                        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                            .setProductId(getString(R.string.billing_product_id))
                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                            .build()
                    )
                )
                .build()

        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { _, productDetailsList ->
            launchPurchaseFlow(
                productDetailsList[0]
            )
        }
    }


    // запуск покупки
    private fun launchPurchaseFlow(productDetails: ProductDetails?) {
        val productList = ArrayList<ProductDetailsParams>()
        productList.add(
            ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductDetails(productDetails!!)
                .build()
        )

        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductDetailsParamsList(productList)
            .build()

        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams)
    }


    // запуск покупки
    private fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                    .build()
            ) {
                for (pur in purchase.products) {
                    if (pur.equals(getString(R.string.billing_product_id), ignoreCase = true)) {
                        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Purchase is successful")
                        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Yay! Purchased")
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.snackbar_reset_app))
                        SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion = true

                        consumePurchase(purchase)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // запуск покупки
    private fun consumePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        val params = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            .build()

        billingClient.consumeAsync(params) { _, s ->
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Consuming Successful: $s")
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Product Consumed")
        }
    }


    // обработка ошибок о покупках с google play
    private fun handleBillingError(responseCode: Int) {
        val errorMessage: String = when (responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE -> "Billing service is currently unavailable. Please try again later."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.DEVELOPER_ERROR -> "An error occurred while processing the request. Please try again later."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> "This feature is not supported on your device."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> "You already own this item."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED -> "You do not own this item."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE -> "This item is not available for purchase."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED -> "Billing service has been disconnected. Please try again later."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> "Billing service is currently unavailable. Please try again later."
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED -> "The purchase has been canceled."
            else -> "An unknown error occurred."
        }
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, errorMessage)
    }

}
```

Comment: насколько я знаю acknowledgePurchase возвращает результат который нужно проверить на OK